# how do you revert on svn before doing svn update in Bamboo C.I

Tags: jenkins

How do you revert on svn before doing svn update in Bamboo C.I?  I know that this is possible in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scipt task before the checkout task that runs svn revert.

Comment: ok, i'll try that